# Where's the right place for text lookup in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Keeping in line with "the Rails Way", what would be the correct/accepted/best practice method of outputting text in a view like this:

```
<!-- show.html.erb -->

<% if @post.status == "PUBLISHED" %>
   Big long text about being published.
<% elsif @post.status == "DRAFT" %>
   Big long text about under being a draft post.
<% elsif @post.status == "UNDER_REVIEW" %>
   Big long text about being under review.
<% end %>
```

Should this be delegated to a method? If so, where should that method be defined?

Comment: Moving this to helper will clean your html file a bit.

Comment: Apart from my answer, I'd like to mention, based on your FSM-like status, that you should probably be using some workflow gem (like `gem 'workflow'` for instance) to have ready methods and programmed transitions for your logic.

Comment: @RubyRacer, thanks but that was just an example code sample I made up as I was writing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know MCV, but in ruby terms:

```
<% case @post.status %>
    <% when "PUBLISHED" %>
        Big long text about being published.
    <% when "DRAFT" %>
        Big long text about under being a draft post.
    <% when "UNDER_REVIEW" %>
        Big long text about being under review.
<% end %>
```

If, however, your text is static or dependent on or calculable from  the status, you could render specific partials. For instance, you might have:

`_PUBLISHED.html.erb`, 
`_DRAFT.html.erb` and 
`_UNDER_REVIEW.html.erb`.

In that case, you might replace everything with just this:

```
<%= render "#{@post.status}" %>
```

Comment: +1, I was about to suggest partials myself but you beat me to it. Normally view related logic either goes into a view helper or a view decorator (draper gem), but since we're dealing with "big long text" here I think partials is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Nominally the view, if you're thinking only in terms of MVC.  Unless the text is inherent to the data model, which I could potentially understand, this is view-logic.

That said, to answer your question about delegating to a method, I think it should and the right place for it would be in a decorator.  The [Draper gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) is intended for just this type of object-oriented logic for your views.  You could try taking a look there.

Answer (score 1):

I usually like to extract this kind of logic to either a decorator (via [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)) or a separate class

#### Decorator

```
#app/decorators/post_decorator.rb
class PostDecorator < Drapper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  def decorated_text
    if status == 'PUBLISHED'
      return "big published text"
    elsif status == 'DRAFT'
      return "big draft text"
    elsif status == 'UNDER_REVIEW'
      return "big under_review text"
    end
  end
end
```

with which you would be able to call `@post.decorated_text` on your decorated `@post`

#### Separate class

```
class PostText
  def initialize(post)
    @post = post
  end

  def decorated_text
    if @post.status == 'PUBLISHED'
      return "big published text"
    elsif @post.status == 'DRAFT'
      return "big draft text"
    elsif @post.status == 'UNDER_REVIEW'
      return "big under_review text"
    end
  end
end
```

with which you would be able to use it as

```
@text = PostText.new(@post)
text = @text.decorated_text
```

In both cases your view should be clean

```
<!-- show.html.erb -->

<%= @decorated_post.decorated_text %>
```

or

```
<!-- show.html.erb -->

<%= @text.decorated_text %>
```

#### NOTE:

At times it has been proven useful to provide extra templates for each state, but only if the part that changes has some kind of html inside it or it is really big.